# NestJS 8 - Inject Service without constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm trying to load config using ConfigModule as below

```html
 ConfigModule.forRoot({
      ignoreEnvFile: true,
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [async () => await fetchConfig(new ServiceConfigurationService())],
    }),
```

Inside ServiceConfigurationService class I want to inject other service class which I have exposed through a npm module. Is there any way to inject service instead through a constructor? I have tried property bases DI, it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you control the initialization of `ServiceConfigurationService` by yourself, you can use any tool to perform the injection.

But if you want to use nestjs's DI container, you must do that through nestjs providers as the docs shown here: https://docs.nestjs.com/providers